# The type or namespace ,,blabla" error appearing after i build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title suggests, when i'm trying to build my unity project on my phone i get:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InitializeOnLoadMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

But the project is working fine. No errors in visual studio, no errors while playing the game, nothing.
I tried to change the solution .NET version in visual studio from

> .NET Framework 4.7.1

to

> unity 3.5 .net full Base Class Libraries

(i did that without really knowing what i was doing so maybe i did something wrong)

But then i got even more errors. Can someone please explain what to do? i fell helpless

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ExecuteOnRefresh : MonoBehaviour
{
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void OnInitialized()
    {
        var propTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Property)).GetTypes().Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Property)));
        EntityBuild.PROP_NAMES = propTypes.Select(type => type.ToString()).ToList();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share the code?so we have a better understanding what going on

Comment: done, but i don't think it's code related. Unity and Visual Studio don't show any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InitializeOnLoadMethod` attribute is editor-only stuff. Either you have to move your script in a folder named "Editor", or surround your code between `#if UNITY_EDITOR` - `#endif`, so Unity won't try to compile it into the build.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/InitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html

Comment: Woah, I didn't know that's a thing. Thanks